# How to get queryset value after search using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I using  Django Rest Framework and I need **queryset** that filtered by using Search, This **queryset** send to CarSerializer. **empidlong** from  CarSerializer will have **empid** for Requests JSON from specific url(192.168.10.3).

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from .models import getData
from .serializers import CarSerializer
import requests
class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = getData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    #search_fields = ('plate_no')
    __basic_fields = ('plate_no',)
    search_fields = __basic_fields

  def get_search_fields(self, view, request):
            if request.query_params.get('khai'):
                return ('plate_no',)


            x= super(CarViewSet, self).get_search_fields(view, request)
            serializer = CarSerializer(x)
            data = serializer.data
            for a in data:
                empid= a['empidlong']
                requests.get('http://192.168.10.3/GetEmployees/'+empid +'/Y')
            return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Django filter it will be ease with viewsets

### views.py

```
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_class = getDataFilter
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    queryset = getData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

create a file filters.py, there you specify the fields to filter with all conditions,

```
import django_filters
from .models import getData

class getDataFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'first_name': ['iexact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
            'last_name': ['iexact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
        }
```

urls format is like this,

```
https://localhost:8000/xxxx/?last_name__iexact=xx
```